# change column width when double click to edit in a cell of AG grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using Ag grid in my Angular Project. I crated a custom cell editor to edit because I have multiple input types and Ag grid's simple editor was not able to manage that. But now, the problem I am facing is, My editor's width is more than cell width and it is not looking good because its going out of the cell.

[image]

What I want to do is

when I double click on any cell The respective column's width get increased by some value I pass.

I tried the documentation but no luck,
I tried this solution from document

```js
autoSizeAll(skipHeader) {
    var allColumnIds = [];
    this.gridColumnApi.getAllColumns().forEach(function(column) {
      allColumnIds.push(column.colId);
    });
    this.gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds, skipHeader);
  }
```

but still no way to give width value.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answer it was provided in the Ag Grid documentation.

added  function on cell double click event

```js
setCustomSize(){
this.gridColumnApi.setColumnWidth(key, width)
}
```